# Axis2 Deployed vs Generated Service WSDL Differences

Tags: namespaces, wsdl, client, apache-axis

I have a web service built with axis2. Also, I have used Java2WSDL utility provided by axis2 to generate a WSDL from my class (not the deployed services) at build time.

Then I generated a client via wsimport for both i.e. Deployed Web Service in Java EE Application Server and from generated WSDL file. The problem is that generated code is different in terms of packages and mamespaces and because of that the client generated from WSDL file is not working as it complains about the namespace mismatch....on jboss I see following exception;

```
13:46:04,524 ERROR [RPCMessageReceiver] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getLanguage
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: namespace mismatch require http://CustomerServiceWs found http://customer.webservices.temenos.com
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:177)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:144)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I used following command to generate my WSDL file from Class File;

```
java2wsdl.bat -o C:\Temp -tn http://CustomerServiceWs -cn com.temenos.webservices.customer.CustomerServiceWS
```

could you please help me sort out this problem or suggest a better way to approach this problem.

Thanks,

--

Sjunejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure the namespace in your schema matches with the NameSpace of the WSDL, to frank enough i do not even like the idea of using Axis2 because of so many problems it has.. anyways try matching the namespace of your xsd with that of your wsdl and make sure all your names of the request and response are similar.

Comment: I know its a namespace problem as I can see that in the generated code but how to fix it?